# Variables in Array (PHP)?

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I have a simple iPhone application I am making that will upload pictures to Facebook. To do this, I have to put multiple files on the server. From that, it will go to Facebook. I have my PHP code below that will do that server-side.

The problem is, when I put a variable in the array, it won't work. I have tried all the different options and it's not working out for me.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

```
$args = array(
'message' => 'Photo from the ******** iPhone Application.',
'$short_url' => '$short_url'
);

$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$album_id.'/photos?access_token='.$get_facebook_token;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
//returns the photo id
print_r(json_decode($data,true));
```

Comment: Okay, all the quotations look fine here, what do you get as a result, and what were you expecting?

Comment: What is this? `'$short_url' => '@$short_url'` | Try `'short_url' => $short_url` in its place. Single quotes `''`, do not interpolate.

Comment: You're right. The @ threw me off track there.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments! Here's what I had to do:

- I removed the '' and facebook didn't reconize it.
- I figured it had to do something with the mysql code so I did it a little different and it worked. Now they go to a database, and I run a cron job with it every minute to do it. I think it's a better method because if it fails, It can run again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using single quotes were you probably should be using a variable directly or double quotes so the variable gets interpolated:

```
$args = array(
    ...,
   "short_url" => "@$short_url",
);
```

Or something like that. Depends on the supposed form field names. And "@$var" probaby leads to a file upload with curl.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `''`s around the variable so it won't be treated as a string.

```
$args = array(
 'message' => 'Photo from the ******** iPhone Application.',
 'short_url' => $short_url
);
```

Comment: do you think it is what he needs?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need

```
"short_url" => $short_url
```